String values parameters doesn't appear in crystal report
I am working on a program where I use Visual Studio 2019 and Crystal Report version CR13SP26. I have a problem which is when I try to create parameter (type : string). It ​​does not appear in the list.
String values parameters doesn't appear in crystal report:


Change 'List of Values' drop-down from Static to Dynamic.

Thanks but can you explain more?

If my answer doesn't immediately solve the issue, I probably didn't understand the question.  Consider explaining your question with more details.
